# Sort any random list of files by modification date

Tags: perl, bash

Looking for generic way how to sort a random list of files by its modification time, so something like:

```
./make_list_of_files | some_sorter_by_mtime
```

my currect solution is (here the `make_list_of_files` is the `find` command):

```
find / -type f -print |\
  perl -nle 'push @in,$_;END {@out = sort{ (stat($a))[9] <=> (stat($b))[9] } @in; $,="\n";print @out}'
```

exists some simpler solution (e.g. without perl)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `some_sorter_by_mtime` should be for example:

```
xargs stat -f "%m %N" | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

the idea behind is:

- print out file modification time and the filename
- sort the output numerically (so by modification time)
- cut out the time field

so,

```
find / -type f -print | xargs stat -f "%m %N" | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

Comment: Accept! This is nice and short... thanx.

Comment: This is faster than my previous solution. I edited my answer after   I see emix's solution and stole the xargs ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
find / -type f -print | xargs ls -l --time-style=full-iso | sort -k6 -k7 | sed 's/^.* \//\//'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my `ls` havn't --time-style parameter, but YES, this looks as a very nice solution.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, without perl:

```
find / -type f -exec ls -lrt '{}' \+
```

Guru.

Comment: This will have unexpected results as the `ls` command line is of limited length, and multiple invocations of `ls` will only sort the files in each separate invocation. Besides, this is not a "generic way to sort a _random_ list of files by modification time".

Comment: @lanzz thank you for comment. Your english is much better for explanation of the problem. ;)